# Admins can't edit each other's posts

Tags: users, permissions

After I imported content from another wordpress site using the WXR export/import tools, my admins can't edit each other's posts.  This is really aggravating because I can't figure out how to change this.  And it doesn't just related to imported content.  I can create two brand new admins, each one creates an entry, but neither one can edit the other's posts.

On the post listing page, it doesn't even show an Edit link on or below the title, and there's no checkbox for bulk editing, if the logged-in user isn't the author.  I don't have this problem with pages, but it does effect any Custom Post Types set as 'capability_type' => 'post'

I have no idea how this happened or how to undo it. Please help before I pull all my hair out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it figured out.  For some reason, current_user_can was returning false when an admin went to edit other user's posts... I have no idea how admins lost the ability to do this, but putting this into functions.php is a workable bandaid that restores admin edit capabilities;

```
$administrator = get_role('administrator');
$administrator->add_cap('edit_others_posts');
```