# How do I fix "You are not allowed to edit this item." for Admins on existing posts?

Tags: admin, permissions

I'm doing some work for a new client (non-tech, their former tech person left). Their version of Wordpress is 4.3.2.

I have an admin account and I'm unable to edit existing posts. I can create new ones and edit those, but I'm unable to edit existing posts.

The edit links don't show and if I put in a url I construct myself like (*`/wp-admin/post.php?post=1375&action=edit`*)

I get this error message:

> You are not allowed to edit this item.

I have full access to the filesystem, database, etc. how do I fix this issue so I can edit existing posts through the WordPress UX?

I see the user Role Editor plugin is installed.

I activated it and updated it. It shows that administrators have full permissions.

[image: administrators have full permissions]

Comment: Are you 100% sure your user has the Administrator role? If yes then this might be due to some plugin so the standard debug procedure follows: Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme. See if the issue persists. If it works now enable everything one by one and check when it breaks.

Comment: Thanks @kraftner. I'm 99.9% sure :) In the user roles it shows as administrator and I've created another user as well (same result) thanks for the tip on disabling plugins (49 total 23 active, 26 inactive)

Comment: Wow with that many plugins your chances of one being the culprit are pretty good. Also you are not doing this on the live site but a local clone, right? :)

Comment: lol, I wish there was a clone site. I haven't disabled them all yet I don't know enough about WP to know if that can cause issues. I think I'm going to try this (hack?) http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65418/admins-cant-edit-each-others-posts I'm trying to locate the right functions.php file (there are a lot)

Comment: Well I'm out then. Messing with admin rights and plugins on a live site is like conducting heart surgery with dirty hands and blindfolded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by editing /wp-includes/capabilities.php

The code was

```
function current_user_can( $capability ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $current_user ) )
        return false;

    $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 1 );
    $args = array_merge( array( $capability ), $args );

    return call_user_func_array( array( $current_user, 'has_cap' ), $args );
}
```

and I changed it to

```
function current_user_can( $capability ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $current_user ) )
        return false;

    if (is_admin())
        return true;
    $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 1 );
    $args = array_merge( array( $capability ), $args );

    return call_user_func_array( array( $current_user, 'has_cap' ), $args );
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't modify system WordPress files as next time you update the core, your changes will get overwritten

Comment: I second @Stan's comment. Editing Core files is a temporary solution that could be overwritten without you realising it if you have auto updates on.